# What's the difference between sum and torch.sum for a torch Tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I get the same results when using either the python sum or torch.sum so why did torch implement a sum function? Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing, `torch.sum` calls `tensor.sum` and python's `sum` calls `__add__` (or `__radd__` when needed) which calls `tensor.sum` again

so the only difference is in the number of function calls, and `tensor.sum()` should be the fastest (when you have small tensors and the function call's overhead is considerable)

Comment: I have found `sum` to be useful on occasion, for example, to compute a loss over a sequence generated by a network. One can use a generator to get loss tensors and sum them without having to create an intermediate tensor with `torch.stack/cat`. I _believe_ that this is more efficient or can save you running out of memory if you're dealing with large tensors or long sequences.

Answer (score 2):

It appears python's sum can take generators as input, whereas torch.sum cannot:

`import torch`
`print( sum( torch.ones(1)*k for k in torch.arange(10)))`
returns `tensor([45.])`, whereas:

`print( torch.sum( torch.ones(1)*k for k in torch.arange(10)))`
raises `TypeError: sum(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not generator`

I'm assuming that pyTorch's backpropagation would get in trouble with lazy evaluation of the generator, but not sure about that, yet.

Comment: No troubles with backprop as it just calls `__add__`  and builds graph over it.